# can not generate necessary file when compile IDL file in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, com, compilation, idl

i'm learning about COM through an internet tutorial(http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/com-tech/activex/tutorials/article.php/c5567/Step-by-Step-COM-Tutorial.htm). The first thing is creating a IDL file and compile it to create another 5 files. The detail is after:

1. Open VS2010
2. Create Win32 DLL project name AddObj
3. Add IAdd.idl file with the content

   > import "unknwn.idl";
   >
   > [
   >   object,
   >   uuid(1221db62-f3d8-11d4-825d-00104b3646c0),
   >   helpstring("interface IAdd is used for implementing a super-fast addition Algorithm")
   >   ]
   >
   > interface IAdd : IUnknown
   >   {
   >   HRESULT SetFirstNumber(long nX1);
   >
   > HRESULT SetSecondNumber(long nX2);
   >   HRESULT DoTheAddition([out,retval] long *pBuffer);
   >   };
   >
   > [
   >   uuid(3ff1aab8-f3d8-11d4-825d-00104b3646c0),
   >   helpstring("Interfaces for Code Guru algorithm implementations .")
   >   ]
   >   library CodeGuruMathLib
   >   {
   >   importlib("stdole32.tlb");
   >   importlib("stdole2.tlb");
   >
   > interface IAdd;
   >   }

After that, follow the tutorial, if i compile IAdd.idl file, it will generate:

--IAdd.h    Contains the C++ style interface declarations.

--dlldata.c     Contains code for proxy DLL. Useful when invoking the object on a different process/computer.

--IAdd.tlb  Binary file , with a well defined format that completely describes our interface IAdd along with all it's methods. This file is to be distributed to all the clients of our COM component.

--IAdd_p.c  Contains marshalling code for proxy DLL. Useful while invoking the object on a different process/computer.

--IAdd_i.c  Contains the interface IIDs

but when i compile IAdd by right click it and choose compile in shortcut menu, there is no file being generate. But when open view class, i can see IAdd interface with some method.

I also try it by compile it manually by download midl.exe from internet and run in command line but it failed.

I fine a lot of material by google and all said that i can compile idl file by visual studio but i try many time, on my both computer but no file being generate after i compile idl file. I also install new Win7, new visual studio 2010 ultimate but nothing change.

Comment: You've only declared an interface, it is nothing but a declaration.  Now you need to *implement* it.  Use the ATL simple object wizard to have some hope of getting this correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just created a new project and created a new idl file with the code you specified.If i right click and choose compile it works just fine (VS2010 Ultimate).
Did you choose the correct filetype in the fileproperties of VS?
It should be "IDL File".

Have you used the VS Command Prompt as you tried to compile it manually?
(The VS Command Prompt will set all necessary environment variables)

Comment: thanks. I made routin again, it compiled ok as every time and no extra file appear in "solution exploier" but it really made 4 file in AddObj directory. I never watch the AddObj directory before, ;)), but it still not have IAdd.tbl file. I also knew about visual studio command prompt after your help and try it, but no thing happen, there is no file being generate after the command. Anyway, it's really happy when i know how to compile idl file. thanks you so much